# set maximum width possible between two elements

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements:

```
<button class="a"></button>
<div class="b"></div>
<button class="c"></button>
```

And this is the style:

```
.a {
    width: 30px;
}
.c {
    width: 50px;
    float:right;
}
```

I want that div .b will be inline (without line break) and that it's width will be the maximum width available between .a and .c.
In addition, I don't want to use absolute positioning.
Any idea?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You are trying to close a `button` with a closing `</div>`

Comment: Thanks, fixed it. It was only on the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place your `.b` element *after* the other two, float one to the right and one to the left. Then give `.b` overflow:hidden, which makes it stretch to the available width while clearing previously floated elements:

You also have invalid HTML, fix that!

**HTML**

```
<button class="a"></button>
<button class="c"></button>
<div class="b">A</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a { width: 30px; float:left; }
.c { width: 50px; float:right; }
.b { overflow:hidden; }
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/oGeez/X5HJN/)

Answer (score 1):

try this for b class.

`.b {max-width:100%;}`

Answer (score 0):

remove float, and try it this way :

```
.a {
    width: 30px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.b {
    width:calc(100% - 100px); /* key */
    display:inline-block;
}
.c {
    width: 50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[**demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nFy9j/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
button.a, div.b, button.c
{
    display: block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
}

button.a, button.c
{
  width: 25%;
}

div.b
{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/fs7aF/

You should consider using a grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to float both buttons and let the div fill the remaining space by itself (as divs do)

```
<button class="a"></button>
<button class="c"></button>
<div class="b">test</div>
```

with

```
.a {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
}
.c {
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
}
```

optional, to make sure the div stays *between* those buttons, even in further lines:

```
.b { 
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}
```